# Comparing Column A to B and B to A and Copy Entire Row of Missing and Added to New Sheets Respectively

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I'm trying to figure out the best way to attack this problem and my head is spinning a bit, I'm not sure if I should use `For Each Cell` or `Arrays` or `Collections` to do some comparisons and copy entire rows to new sheets. I'd like to use `Arrays` but my code only uses the values of column but then I have to go back and re-loop through column to find "missing values" and copy entire row which seems to defeat part of the point of using arrays (speed/efficiency).

I'm looking for advice on the best way to tackle this issue, but I'll post my array code as well.

First off, example data:

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

The idea is Sheet1 is yesterdays report and sheet2 is todays.

My goal is two more sheets (or one combo sheet, but that seems unnecessary hard as I need to do total calculations on each result sheet search results respectively by totaling one of the columns, but not the value in column A)

ItemsAdded:

A6 AV6

ItemsRemoved:

A5 AV5

So basically it is finding what items where removed and what was added comparing sheet2 to sheet1 column A.

So far I was able to get that part, without the row values and I'm really wondering if I'm attacking this correctly.

IE: This gets the missing/added items. Now I need to go and fetch the entire row for the values in each sheet, but am unsure how and the code is starting to look long and repeating.

```
Public Function RangeToArray(Rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To Rng.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each r In Rng
        arr(i) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
     Next r

    RangeToArray = arr
End Function
Public Sub Compare_Columns_A_and_B_with_Arrays()

 Dim wb As Workbook, wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, Missing As Worksheet, Added As Worksheet
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
 Set wsA = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set wsB = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 Set Missing = wb.Worksheets("Missing")
 Set Added = wb.Worksheets("Added")

Dim lRowA As Long
 lRowA = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Dim sourceArray As Variant, srcrng As Range
 Set srcrng = wsA.Range("A1:A" & lRowA)
 sourceArray = RangeToArray(srcrng)

Dim lRowB As Long
 lRowB = wsB.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
 Dim verifyArray As Variant, verifyrng As Range
 Set verifyrng = wsB.Range("A1:A" & lRowB)
 verifyArray = RangeToArray(verifyrng)



For Each arrval In sourceArray
 IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(verifyArray, arrval)) > -1)
 If IsInArray = False Then
  'Debug.Print arrval
  Dim lRowMissing As Long
  lRowMissing = Missing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  Missing.Range("A" & lRowMissing).Value = arrval
 End If
Next arrval

For Each arrval In verifyArray
 IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(sourceArray, arrval)) > -1)
 If IsInArray = False Then
  'Debug.Print arrval
  Dim lRowAdded As Long
  lRowAdded = Added.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  Added.Range("A" & lRowAdded).Value = arrval
 End If
Next arrval


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this statement: "*fetch the entire row*"? Do you want to compare `A1` & `AV1` with yesterday's and today's data?

Comment: Just an idea: you can pass the selected key values in an array to `Criteria1` of a `Range.AutoFilter` and then copy the visible cells with `Range().SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Comment: @MaciejLos the idea is on the "final results" WS I need the entire row for the missing and added values from `sheet1/2` respectively. Eg `A5 AV5`

Comment: @AcsErno I actually really like that idea!, partly because I'm familiar with that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actuallaly ended up using @AceErno's comment and using `AutoFilter` to pull the `EntireRows` of the data that was found by comparing arrays using the code in my original question. I'm not sure happy with my code, but it works and I can look into that later when I am feeling up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to achieve something like this:

[image]

In a `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` there are headers (in my case i've used `Header 1` and `Header 2`.

In a result sheet:

1. `Yesterday` column holds an information about count of `A(x)` data in `Sheet1`.
2. `Today` column holds an information about count of `A(x)` data in `Sheet2`.

I have used below code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareData()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wshYesterday As Worksheet, wshToday As Worksheet, wshResult As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wshResult = wbk.Worksheets("Result")
    
    On Error GoTo Err_CompareData

    If Not wshResult Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wbk.Worksheets("Result").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    Set wshYesterday = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wshToday = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wshResult = wbk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wshToday)
    wshResult.Name = "Result"
    wshResult.Range("A1") = "Header 1"
    wshResult.Range("B1") = "Header 2"
    wshResult.Range("C1") = "Yesterday"
    wshResult.Range("D1") = "Today"
    'find last entry in yesterdays data
    i = wshYesterday.Range("A" & wshYesterday.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    'copy into result sheet
    wshYesterday.Range("A2:B" & i).Copy wshResult.Range("A" & j)
    j = j + i - 1
    'find last entry in todays data and copy into result sheet
    i = wshToday.Range("A" & wshToday.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wshToday.Range("A2:B" & i).Copy wshResult.Range("A" & j)
    'remove duplicates
    i = wshResult.Range("A" & wshResult.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wshResult.Range("A2:B" & i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
    j = 2
    i = wshResult.Range("A" & wshResult.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Do While j <= i
        'count values stored in column #1 in yesterdays data
        k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wshYesterday.UsedRange, wshResult.Range("A" & j))
        wshResult.Range("C" & j) = k
        'count todays data
        k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wshToday.UsedRange, wshResult.Range("A" & j))
        wshResult.Range("D" & j) = k
        j = j + 1
    Loop

Exit_CompareData:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshYesterday = Nothing
    Set wshToday = Nothing
    Set wshResult = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_CompareData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_CompareData

End Sub
```

Feel free to improve it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know exactly what you want, but here is a Power Query solution (available in Excel 2010+) that creates a table summarizing what's been removed and/or added.

I assumed your data was in tables named `Yesterday` and `Today`. Change the table names in the `Source =`  lines to match your real data.

**M-Code**

```
let
   //Read in the data tables
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Yesterday"]}[Content],
    Yesterday = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Today"]}[Content],
    Today = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

    /*Using the appropriate JoinKind, create two different tables for
      itemsAdded and itemsRemove*/
        itemsAddedTBL = Table.NestedJoin(Today,"Column1",Yesterday,"Column1","TBL",JoinKind.LeftAnti),

        //Remove the unneeded TBL column
        itemsAdded = Table.RemoveColumns(itemsAddedTBL,"TBL"),

        //Add a column stating "Added"
        itemsAddedLBL = Table.AddColumn(itemsAdded,"Add/Remove", each "Added", type text),

        //Repeat the above for removed items
        itemsRemovedTBL = Table.NestedJoin(Yesterday,"Column1",Today,"Column1","TBL",JoinKind.LeftAnti),
        itemsRemoved = Table.RemoveColumns(itemsRemovedTBL,"TBL"),
        itemsRemovedLBL = Table.AddColumn(itemsRemoved, "Add/Remove", each "Removed",type text),

        //combine (append) the two tables into one
        comb = Table.Combine({itemsAddedLBL,itemsRemovedLBL})       

in
    comb
```

[image]